# Facebook SDK Error: FBSDKVersion-generated.h file not found

Tags: ios, facebook

I've installed the Facebook SDK but when I try to build, it fails and I get an error from FBRequestConnection.m that "FBSDKVersion-generated.h file not found." The comment above the #import line says "// Note: This file is auto-generated by a Run Script build step." but I can't find a script for it anywhere.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change this code line

```
#import "FBSDKVersion-generated.h"
```

to

```
#define FB_IOS_SDK_VERSION_STRING @"3.0.5.b"
```

3.0.5.b - last version at this time

Comment: Thanks... now I get a Semantic Issue - Use of undeclared identifier 'FB_IOS_SDK_VERSION_STRING' in the same file (same result as when I tried commenting out the #import of the generated file above).

Comment: "Build Succeeded"  Thank you!